# Adding to concurrent collections

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrent-collections

When working with a concurrent collection (for example ConcurrentDictionary) should I use TryAdd method, or just a plain old index assignment? I mean, do TryAdd method blocks when adding, so if another thread would try to remove the value it would have to wait until add is complete?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267291.aspx That's enough? Nothing in sense of thread safety.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prefix `try` has nothing to do with thread safety. It is just exception-free version of `Add`.

Comment: So if I want my code to be thread safe what should I do? Are concurrent collections thread safe "by default", and so I may as well just use index assignment?

Answer (score 2):

Both the indexer's setter and `Add` call `TryAdd` internally.

```
public TValue this[TKey key]
{
  get { /*Irrelevant*/ }
  set
  {
    if ((object) key == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
    TValue resultingValue;
    this.TryAddInternal(key, value, true, true, out resultingValue);
  }
}
```

`Add` method:

```
void IDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
{
  if (!this.TryAdd(key, value))
    throw new ArgumentException(this.GetResource("ConcurrentDictionary_KeyAlreadyExisted"));
}
```